# How to select the a field of an object being a field of a table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

to test the code: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8cf685ff21a69c5e83a9861a56a71cbb

I have a table. One of its fields is an object. I only want to select a field of this object.

```
create type a as object(
  a  integer
)

-- I have succeeded to select the object
with b(c) as (select a(2) from dual) select c from b

--but I have failed to only select the field of this object
with b(c) as (select a(2) from dual) select c.a from b
```

> ORA-00904: "C"."A": invalid identifier

Comment: Your question should be used as a model for posting questions here. You reproduced your issue (with all its relevant details) in a very small example, you posted all the required code, you explained what you expected/required and what happened instead, including the error message. +1 even for that alone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the subquery an alias and then reference the alias:

```sql
with b(c) as (
  select a(2) from dual
)
select b.c.a
from   b b
```

*Note: Yes, I gave it the same alias as the table name. It might be less confusing to give it a different alias but the important thing is to use an alias and then refer to it as `<table_alias>.<column_identifier>.<attribute_identifier>`.*

Outputs:

> | C.A |
> | --- |
> | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=88bb50f78d00288d14bca7a2eec695b7)*

Comment: Perhaps to make it a bit clearer: There are **two** requirements to make this work. First, the table must be referenced (otherwise, the identifier with a single dot in it is treated as "table.column" rather than "column.attribute"); and, second - and for reasons known only to Oracle - referencing the table **by name** is invalid. The table **must** be given an alias (even if the alias is the same as the table name!) and then - as in all situations where a table name is given an alias - the table must be referenced by its alias, not by its original name.